# Adjust footer size in MVC 4 Template Visual Studio 2012 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, footer

How do I make the size of the footer in the `_Layout.cshtml` file smaller?

When I create a new view for the project and run it, the footer takes up most of the page if that view is empty.

I would like to make the footer a smaller size like 10-15% of the page size, I don't want it to grow depending on the contents of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're calling the "footer" is not all the footer. Webpages have no real concept of page-height as you would find in more traditional media such as print. The height of the page is however much space is required for the given amount of content. In cases where content is minimal, the "footer" follows what content is there and then the rest of the browser window view is *empty*. Depending on CSS that's applied, the page "background" color or image can and often does extend past the actual "page" boundary, and I think this background extension plus the footer is what you're considering as just the "footer".

The point is that the actual footer is not growing or shrinking in height depending on the page content, but rather there's simply just more or less empty space *following* the footer. As to how to "remove" this, you can either give the page and/or footer a different background color so that the two are distinguished more readily or you could potentially fix the footer at the bottom of the page at all times. There's tons of information online about how to do so whichever route you choose.